# How to return value from C++ main application to C# GUI application?

Tags: c#, c++, user-interface

I would like to know how to do this? For example, if exception occurs in C++ main application, how do send something to the GUI application? Any simple example would be appreciated.

Comment: well, it depends how you want to handle this. you can have a try catch and in the catch you return an error code known also from the C# application, if you are in full control of both applications.

Comment: Does the GUI application start the C++ application?

Comment: Yes the GUI is the front end and pass the arguments to C++ main application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the C# GUI app starts the C++ console app, then the **exit code** of the latter (the return value of the `main()` function) can be accessed by the former, see the example here: [Process.ExitCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exitcode.aspx). The general solution is to use some form of **InterProcess Communication** (IPC). Windows examples: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485650/wcf-fastest-interprocess-communication).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the two applications in C++ & C# are different processes, you cannot do that.
(but you could return an error code -between 0 and 255- with `exit` in the child process and get it with `waitpid` in the parent process).

However (at least on Linux) you could have a textual bi-directionnal channel (on Linux, with named or anonymous pipes,  or AF_UNIX sockets) and define a protocol between the two processes.

Comment: -1 for "cannot do that" -- the C++ app most assuredly *could* send information about the error to the C# app. If the C# process launched the C++ one, it could easily capture its stderr, or use pipes for communication. If the processes were started independently, they could use named pipes, or sockets, or shared memory.

Comment: I disagree, the C++ app cannot do that *directly*; it has (as you and I are suggesting) to define some application specific protocol. There is no direct function call to transmit an exception from a C++ process to a C# one (at least in the Linux world, where C# is Mono) ...

Comment: OP didn't ask for something fancy like re-throwing the C++ exception as a CLR exception. The question was "how do send **something** to the GUI application" (emphasis mine). Your answer of "cannot do that" is ridiculous -- sending *something* back is as simple as writing the exception to stderr.

Comment: Yes, but that is a convention, i.e. a protocol.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear for me if Exception happened in your c++ application your application suppose to exit or not?
if your application suppose to exit when error hapend:

1. in your C++ code when error happend use "exit(errorCode)" that errorCode is an integer number
2. in your C# application for process that exwcute your c++ exe, register handler for the Exited event (make sure you set EnableRaisingEvents on the process to true).
3. in your event handler read "ExitCode" of the process object that run your c++ exe.

but if in your c++ application you handle the error and just want to notify the GUI, One solution is :

1. in c++ application when error happend write the error in one file
2. in C# application we create one thread that read this file and when the content of the file is changed,send one event to main thread.

Note: for communication between two proccess ther is more than one way may be this text help you :http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication

Comment: The C++ application will return something to C# GUI before exiting.

Answer (score 0):

One Way is to use a WCF service. I recently wrote a C# GUI on one machine that needed to communicate with a C++/CLI app on a different machine and I just exchanged information (including error messages) through WCF, it would work equally well running on a single machine. Plus this approach gives you an excuse to learn WCF.