# passing value from windows application to another one

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, parameter-passing, desktop-application

How to pass value from a Windows desktop application to another Windows desktop application?

I'm stuck right now. I don't want to build two different forms in one Winform application.

I need two different Winform application that communicates with each other, one of them send value to other one and the receiver processes the data.
Anyone knows how to do that?

I'd be grateful if you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement interprocess communication, Please check this link [What is the simplest method of inter-process communication between 2 C# processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528652/what-is-the-simplest-method-of-inter-process-communication-between-2-c-sharp-pro)

in this link you can find multiple options to implement interprocess communication such as:

- Windows Communication Foundation
- Windows Messages

Comment: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: It is not always the case, better than just saying duplicated question right?

Comment: Links are helpful thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use WCF for communicating between applications. Have look [WCF - Fastest interprocess communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485650/wcf-fastest-interprocess-communication)

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with Remote Objects using Services (.Net Remoting), then your two application can communicate using this method.

You can refer to this link:
https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/code/227615/simple-net-remoting-demonstration